# How to set an attribute on multiple objects at the same time

Tags: python, dictionary, wildcard

I have built a Memory class to represent a kind of memory, this memory has a bunch of registers of class Register, for simplicity lets just say they have a name and a value as attributes.

This class has been built to work like a dictionary, so I can access each register by their name.

For example:

```py
aMemory   = Memory()
aRegister = aMemory["registerName1"] #Gets an object of type Register with name "registerName1"
```

This allows me to do:

```py
aMemory["registerName1"].value = 12
```

which sets that registers value directly.

Now lets say I have 3 registers: "registerName1", "registerName2" and "registerName3"

I want to do:

```py
aMemory["registerName*"].value = 12 #Notice the '*' wildcard
```

and expected to set the value of all matching registers to 12.

What I tried was implementing the `__getitem__()` function for the Memory class and when detecting a wildcard on the key it would return a generator of some kind for example:

```py
def __getitem__(self, registerId):
        if '*' in registerId or '?' in registerId:
            return filter(lambda register: fnmatch.fnmatch(register.name, registerId), self._registers.values())

        return self._registers[registerId]
```

otherwise would return the Register object with that key.

Now this obviously doesn't work because then the `__setattr__()` that is going to be called is the one on the filter object and not the one on the Register object. But even if I could make the one on Register be called I am not sure I could make this work.

So I guess my question is: Is there any way to achieve this, or do I have to make a function to set all Registers when a wildcard is to be used?

Comment: Can you share the class definition of Memory and Register ?

Comment: Don't you want to create a custom`__setitem__` which sets all matching instances, perhaps looking up all instances in a class variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that holds mutliple `Register` and when you set/get a property on it, it propagates it on every `Register`

```py
class RegistersView:
    _registers: list[Register]

    def __init__(self, registers: list[Register]):
        self._registers = registers

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in ["_registers"]:
            super().__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            for r in self._registers:
                setattr(r, key, value)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in ["_registers"]:
            super().__getattribute__(item)
        else:
            return [getattr(r, item) for r in self._registers]
```

```py
class Memory:
    _registers: dict

    def __init__(self):
        self._registers = {
            "registerName1": Register("registerName1"),
            "registerName2": Register("registerName2"),
            "registerName3": Register("registerName3"),
        }

    def __getitem__(self, registerId):
        if '*' in registerId or '?' in registerId:
            regs = list(filter(lambda register: fnmatch.fnmatch(register.name, registerId), self._registers.values()))
            return RegistersView(regs)

        return self._registers[registerId]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MEMO {self._registers}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aMemory = Memory()
    print(aMemory)
    # MEMO {'registerName1': 0, 'registerName2': 0, 'registerName3': 0}

    aRegister = aMemory["registerName1"]
    aRegister.value = 12

    allReg = aMemory["registerName*"]
    print(aMemory, allReg.value)
    # MEMO {'registerName1': 12, 'registerName2': 0, 'registerName3': 0} [12, 0, 0]

    allReg.value = 14
    print(aMemory, allReg.value)
    # MEMO {'registerName1': 14, 'registerName2': 14, 'registerName3': 14} [14, 14, 14]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working one:

```
import fnmatch


class Register:
    value: int
    name: str

    def __init__(self, name: str, val: int):
        self.name = name
        self.value = val

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{{name: {self.name}, value: {self.value}}}"


class WildCard:
    _registers: list

    def __init__(self, registers: list):
        self._registers = registers

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self._registers}"

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == "_registers":
            super().__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            for reg in self._registers:
                setattr(reg, key, value)


class Memory:
    _registers: dict

    def __init__(self):
        self._registers = {}

    def __getitem__(self, register_id: str):
        if '*' in register_id or '?' in register_id:
            regs = list(filter(lambda register: fnmatch.fnmatch(register.name, register_id), self._registers.values()))
            return WildCard(regs)

        return self._registers[register_id]

    def register(self, item: Register):
        self._registers[item.name] = item

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self._registers}"


aMemory = Memory()
aMemory.register(Register("registerName1", 5))
aMemory.register(Register("registerName2", 88))
aMemory.register(Register("registerName3", 99))
aMemory["registerName1"].value = 123
print(aMemory)
aMemory["*"].value = 678678
print(aMemory)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).